# Chinese character show on input method's ui,php interactive shell in my remote vps can't accept it

Tags: php, interactive

My local environment:debian+lxde(desktop).
`system--lxterminal` enter into a terminal.

```
alias 测试="echo '你好'"
测试
你好
```

Type `php a` in lxterminal ,enter into php interactive shell.

```
php -a
Interactive mode enabled
php > echo "测试";
测试
```

Draw a conclusion:chinese character can be typed and showed in lxterminal and php interactive shell.

Log to my vps with ssh.

```
[root@localhost ~]# php72   -i |grep Readline
Readline Support => enabled
Readline library => EditLine wrapper
alias 测试="echo '你好'"
测试
你好
```

Enter into php interactive shell,chinese character can be typed ,but can't inputed into php interactive shell,you can see chinese character show on chinese input method's ui,php interactive shell in my remote vps can't accept it,why?
It is a dynamic charts below,shows what happened in my vps.
[image]

Comment: I think running the command `locale` could provide information to further debug the problem. I guess the output on your vps will differ from your local output. Note that ssh can forward your locale setting, but the local will still need to be installed as marked in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52704873/593868

Answer (score 0):

Your locale might be incomplete.

Try this:

```
sudo locale-gen zh_CN.UTF-8
```

then reboot

Answer (score -1):

First of all; PHP is not a interactive shell like a Python, its just acting like that. But, i think, if you use that code first, it will be run in your charset;

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
```

and also you can use;

```
declare(encoding="utf-8");
```

but, it wont run on CLI mode.

...just give it try.

Answer (score -3):

It Could be because of the php version.

You should update the versions.

sudo apt-get install ibus-pinyin 
sudo apt-get install ibus-sunpinyin
ibus restart